# Azure Function Bindings/Cosmos DB Delete

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am using typescript/node based azure functions with cosmos/sql api. Right now, I have written all my functions logic using the @azure/cosmos client. I am actively trying to refactor those functions to use input/output bindings instead; however, I am having issues finding examples of deleting entities using bindings.

Example input binding:

```
{
  "type": "cosmosDB",
  "direction": "in",
  "name": "inputDocument",
  "databaseName": "test",
  "collectionName": "test",
  "connectionStringSetting": "COSMOS_DB",
  "id": "{id}",
  "partitionKey": "/tenantId",
  "sqlQuery": ""
}
```

So, to simplify things, my questions are:

1. Can bindings be used to perform delete operations?
2. Is there a way to elegantly inject an @azure/cosmos client in typescript using function bindings? I saw some examples in C#, but I could not find anything typescript related.

Any advice/suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you so much :)

Comment: You can't use a binding to perform a delete operation. You will need to write the delete operation by hand and trigger it from whatever input binding you are using.

Comment: @MarkBrown ..that's what I was afraid of, thanks! Do you know if there is a way to configure a binding to inject a cosmos client so that I don't have to instantiate it and maintain scope/re-usability manually?

Comment: I don't but it's very simple to just add a static reference to the SDK client and instantiate it when a new instance of the function is created.

Comment: Ya, that's how I've been doing it. I just wanted to make sure there wasn't a better way. I saw some examples where it looked like it was injected in C#, but I couldn't find any ts examples. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Can someone of you please post how you solved it?